# Issue in clicking links with window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, popup, onbeforeunload

I have a parent div `content_div` which contain form elements inside a table where user selects multiple row elements(clickable rows),`download link elements` etc.

I have a warning pop up for the user changes done and then try to refresh without clicking save button.

When I select a row and tried to click a download link inside that row,I dont need to show the warning popup.I have the following code but its not working.

If I dont select any rows and tried to click any download links,its not showing any popup,means thats fine.

If I select any rows and then try to click any download links,its showing me the popup which is wrong in my case.

If a user clicks on some other links outside my #content_div,its showing the popup which is true for me.

```js
$(function() {
  var formmodified = 0;

  //click event for each row inside the table
  $(".course_row").click(function(e) {
    -- -- -
    formmodified = 1; //setting the variable to 1 means user 
    has changed something inside the page
  });
  //when form submits 
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    formmodified = 0; //assuming that form is saved after form change
  });
  //function for warning popup
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

  function confirmExit() {
    var element_clicked = 0;
    //#content_div is the main parent which contain the entire
    contents.

    $('#content_div').children().on('click', function(e) {
      console.log('clicked');
      element_clicked = 1; //means the clicked element is inside the #content_div which can be a link or other things

    });
    console.log(element_clicked);
    EDIT: I am always getting element_clicked value as 0 when I click any element inside the div.The value 'clicked'
    is showing.I dont know why the value
    for the variable is not setting to 1


    if (element_clicked) {
      //element_clicked = false;  
      return; // abort beforeunload
    } else {
      if ((!element_clicked) && (formmodified == 1)) {
        return "The selected courses are not saved.
        Do you wish to leave the page ? ";
      }

    }

  }
});
```

Please help me in this case.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just add `click()` event to anchor elements and unbind `onbeforeunload` event.

```js
$("a").on('click', function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

This is just an example. You can add a class or id to the selector so that the event is unbinded only when clicked on a specific anchor tag.

**For example**

```js
$("#content_div a").on('click', function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add `onbeforeunload` to refresh, you either have to do it when any change is trriggered ir just add event when `F5` button is pressed.

To be honest I think that first solution is better, necause then even if user clicks refresh button in a browser the popup will come out.

So you would have to change your functionality.

If you do not want to. Here is a quick add to `F5` button.

```
$(document.body).on("keydown", this, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
        window.onbeforeunload = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: When I used this code,when refreshing the page the popup is not coming.the function is not working

Comment: @Techy this is just an example. You can add a class or id to the selector so that the event is unbinded only when clicked on a specific anchor tag. The jQuery selectors are the same as css

Comment: $(document).on("click", function (event) {
    if($(event.target).closest("#content_div").length == 1)
    {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
       
    }
     else
     {
     window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit; 
   
     }
});   Its working now,but one problem which i face is when I tried to click f5,it is refreshing tha page without popup